# find standard deviation function

Tags: javascript, arrays, standard-deviation

I thought I was finished with my function but turns out it doesn't work as well as I expected. It's supposed to calculate the standard deviation value of an array of numbers.

```
function average (arr) {
  let result = 0
  for (let counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++) {
    result += arr[counter]
  }
  const averageValue = result / arr.length
  return averageValue
}

function standardDeviation (arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return 0
  } else {
  const getAverage = arr.map(x => average(arr) - x)
  const squaredArr = getAverage.map(i => i * i)
  let sum = squaredArr.reduce(function (i, j) {
    return i + j
  })
  const dividedArr = sum / (arr.length - 1)
  return Math.sqrt(dividedArr)
 }
}
```

If I pass the array [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 5, 3], my function should return 1.8998 but it returns 2.031..... why? and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: You should probably provide a runnable example + the formula of the deviation to help people get your point quicker.

Comment: show function "average"

Comment: why do you think 1.9 is the right answer?  hint, look up the definitions of population vs sample variances

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/5L7cLp96/

Comment: I know the answer is 1.8998 because along with this assignment there's several tests that the function must pass. One of them is passing the array [4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3] and returning the number 1.8998.

Comment: Could you just have decimal problems?